# How to return a variable operator like $option[];

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop

Obviously, I can't do this, but is there some way to achieve what I am trying to? I only found can not do's online, but no potential workarounds.

Here is what I am trying to do.

Currently I get the following error... "*Cannot use [] for reading*"

For my theme, I have a framework and the fields from that framework are built using an array that I create.

It looks something like this (minus the 300+ lines of code that I actually use)...

```
$options[] = 
array(
    'title' => 'This Field Tab Title',
    'name' => 'this-field-tab-slug',
    'fields' => 
    array(
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // This Field Option Name
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        array(
            'type' => 'this_field_type',
            'id' => 'this_field_types_id',
        ),
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // This Field Option Name
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        array(
            'type' => 'this_field_type',
            'id' => 'this_field_types_id',
        ),
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // This Field Option Name
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        array(
            'type' => 'this_field_type',
            'id' => 'this_field_types_id',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I am running a grouped field type, so my output has many options/fields within this grouped field/area which can then be added again and again as many times as the user needs. Then I am repeating that whole process/code again but for other taxonomies of the user's site.

So for example, the whole process above applies to post types, categories, tags, archived, etc. etc. So instead of having thousands of lines of repetitive codes, I'm trying to create my own function and pass the variables to that function.

But for the function, I find I can't return $options[];

Here is a screenshot of what I mean by the grouped field that can be added as many times as the user needs.

[image]

And here's an example of the function I am trying to create!

```
public static function layout_settings_config($title_name = '', $title_slug = '', $title_id = '', $query = '') {
    $title_name = 'Post Type';
    $title_slug = 'post-type';
    $title_id = 'post_type';
    $query = 'post_types';
    $options[] = 
    array(
      // all the config array codes in here...
    );
    return $options ??? $options[]; doesn't work.
}
```

Is this possible to achieve what I am trying to a different way? I'm still a little new to creating my own functions and OOP, but nothing I find online for this specific issue with a workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: why not just `return $option;`

Comment: I tried that but nothing returns. Should it, even though the $options[] is containing the array?

Comment: just make sure `$options` has contents, then make the `return` in the end

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. It breaks my theme's framework. I've tried these ideas/solutions before writing this post, which is my fault I should have mentioned that. So I was naturally looking for some alternative way if possible because it seems the commons sense attempt/ways won't work. If you think the $options[] could easily be $options as well and should be about to take both methods, please let me know so I can reach out to the framework's author about it.

Answer (score 1):

$options[] is not object but  it is an operation like function.

**You should return $options** instead.

and, by the way, when you say $options[] = `something`. it actually insert `something` inside an array called $option. so effectively you have to access your options like this.

```
$option[0]->title.
```

So I suggest Instead of making it complex like this.  simply say

```
$option = something.
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. It breaks my theme's framework. I've tried these ideas/solutions before writing this post, which is my fault I should have mentioned that. So I was naturally looking for some alternative way if possible because it seems the commons sense attempt/ways won't work. If you think the $options[] could easily be $options as well and should be about to take both methods, please let me know so I can reach out to the framework's author about it.

Comment: when you return $options, what is the issue? you simply said It breaks your theme's framework.

Comment: frankly speaking form PHP perspective, there is not other solution.  if it breaks your framework, You misunderstood your framework.